# Delete image read after running script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good evening! I have a problem.
I am creating a collection of NFTs using this js file.
What I am trying to modify is that once it reads the images in the layers folder, creates the final image and writes the metadata, these read and used images are deleted in the source folder (${basePath}/layers).

```
const basePath = process.cwd();
const { NETWORK } = require(`${basePath}/constants/network.js`);
const fs = require("fs");
const sha1 = require(`${basePath}/node_modules/sha1`);
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require(`${basePath}/node_modules/canvas`);
const buildDir = `${basePath}/build`;
const layersDir = `${basePath}/layers`;
const {
  format,
  baseUri,
  description,
  background,
  uniqueDnaTorrance,
  layerConfigurations,
  rarityDelimiter,
  shuffleLayerConfigurations,
  debugLogs,
  extraMetadata,
  text,
  namePrefix,
  network,
  solanaMetadata,
  gif,
} = require(`${basePath}/src/config.js`);
const canvas = createCanvas(format.width, format.height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = format.smoothing;
var metadataList = [];
var attributesList = [];
var dnaList = new Set();
const DNA_DELIMITER = "-";
const HashlipsGiffer = require(`${basePath}/modules/HashlipsGiffer.js`);

let hashlipsGiffer = null;

const buildSetup = () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(buildDir)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(buildDir, { recursive: true });
  }
  fs.mkdirSync(buildDir);
  fs.mkdirSync(`${buildDir}/json`);
  fs.mkdirSync(`${buildDir}/images`);
  if (gif.export) {
    fs.mkdirSync(`${buildDir}/gifs`);
  }
};

const getRarityWeight = (_str) => {
  let nameWithoutExtension = _str.slice(0, -4);
  var nameWithoutWeight = Number(
    nameWithoutExtension.split(rarityDelimiter).pop()
  );
  if (isNaN(nameWithoutWeight)) {
    nameWithoutWeight = 1;
  }
  return nameWithoutWeight;
};

const cleanDna = (_str) => {
  const withoutOptions = removeQueryStrings(_str);
  var dna = Number(withoutOptions.split(":").shift());
  return dna;
};

const cleanName = (_str) => {
  let nameWithoutExtension = _str.slice(0, -4);
  var nameWithoutWeight = nameWithoutExtension.split(rarityDelimiter).shift();
  return nameWithoutWeight;
};

const getElements = (path) => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(path)
    .filter((item) => !/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g.test(item))
    .map((i, index) => {
      return {
        id: index,
        name: cleanName(i),
        filename: i,
        path: `${path}${i}`,
        weight: getRarityWeight(i),
      };
    });
};

const layersSetup = (layersOrder) => {
  const layers = layersOrder.map((layerObj, index) => ({
    id: index,
    elements: getElements(`${layersDir}/${layerObj.name}/`),
    name:
      layerObj.options?.["displayName"] != undefined
        ? layerObj.options?.["displayName"]
        : layerObj.name,
    blend:
      layerObj.options?.["blend"] != undefined
        ? layerObj.options?.["blend"]
        : "source-over",
    opacity:
      layerObj.options?.["opacity"] != undefined
        ? layerObj.options?.["opacity"]
        : 1,
    bypassDNA:
      layerObj.options?.["bypassDNA"] !== undefined
        ? layerObj.options?.["bypassDNA"]
        : false,
  }));
  return layers;
};

const saveImage = (_editionCount) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${buildDir}/images/${_editionCount}.png`,
    canvas.toBuffer("image/png")
  );
};

const genColor = () => {
  let hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  let pastel = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, ${background.brightness})`;
  return pastel;
};

const drawBackground = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = background.static ? background.default : genColor();
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, format.width, format.height);
};

const addMetadata = (_dna, _edition) => {
  let dateTime = Date.now();
  let tempMetadata = {
    name: `${namePrefix} #${_edition}`,
    description: description,
    image: `${baseUri}/${_edition}.png`,
    dna: sha1(_dna),
    edition: _edition,
    date: dateTime,
    ...extraMetadata,
    attributes: attributesList,
    compiler: "CryptoGioconda Engine",
  };
  if (network == NETWORK.sol) {
    tempMetadata = {
      //Added metadata for solana
      name: tempMetadata.name,
      symbol: solanaMetadata.symbol,
      description: tempMetadata.description,
      //Added metadata for solana
      seller_fee_basis_points: solanaMetadata.seller_fee_basis_points,
      image: `image.png`,
      //Added metadata for solana
      external_url: solanaMetadata.external_url,
      edition: _edition,
      ...extraMetadata,
      attributes: tempMetadata.attributes,
      properties: {
        files: [
          {
            uri: "image.png",
            type: "image/png",
          },
        ],
        category: "image",
        creators: solanaMetadata.creators,
      },
    };
  }
  metadataList.push(tempMetadata);
  attributesList = [];
};

const addAttributes = (_element) => {
  let selectedElement = _element.layer.selectedElement;
  attributesList.push({
    trait_type: _element.layer.name,
    value: selectedElement.name,
  });
};

const loadLayerImg = async (_layer) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const image = await loadImage(`${_layer.selectedElement.path}`);
    resolve({ layer: _layer, loadedImage: image });
  });
};

const addText = (_sig, x, y, size) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = text.color;
  ctx.font = `${text.weight} ${size}pt ${text.family}`;
  ctx.textBaseline = text.baseline;
  ctx.textAlign = text.align;
  ctx.fillText(_sig, x, y);
};

const drawElement = (_renderObject, _index, _layersLen) => {
  ctx.globalAlpha = _renderObject.layer.opacity;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = _renderObject.layer.blend;
  text.only
    ? addText(
        `${_renderObject.layer.name}${text.spacer}${_renderObject.layer.selectedElement.name}`,
        text.xGap,
        text.yGap * (_index + 1),
        text.size
      )
    : ctx.drawImage(
        _renderObject.loadedImage,
        0,
        0,
        format.width,
        format.height
      );

  addAttributes(_renderObject);
};

const constructLayerToDna = (_dna = "", _layers = []) => {
  let mappedDnaToLayers = _layers.map((layer, index) => {
    let selectedElement = layer.elements.find(
      (e) => e.id == cleanDna(_dna.split(DNA_DELIMITER)[index])
    );
    return {
      name: layer.name,
      blend: layer.blend,
      opacity: layer.opacity,
      selectedElement: selectedElement,
    };
  });
  return mappedDnaToLayers;
};

/**
 * In some cases a DNA string may contain optional query parameters for options
 * such as bypassing the DNA isUnique check, this function filters out those
 * items without modifying the stored DNA.
 *
 * @param {String} _dna New DNA string
 * @returns new DNA string with any items that should be filtered, removed.
 */
const filterDNAOptions = (_dna) => {
  const dnaItems = _dna.split(DNA_DELIMITER);
  const filteredDNA = dnaItems.filter((element) => {
    const query = /(\?.*$)/;
    const querystring = query.exec(element);
    if (!querystring) {
      return true;
    }
    const options = querystring[1].split("&").reduce((r, setting) => {
      const keyPairs = setting.split("=");
      return { ...r, [keyPairs[0]]: keyPairs[1] };
    }, []);

    return options.bypassDNA;
  });

  return filteredDNA.join(DNA_DELIMITER);
};

/**
 * Cleaning function for DNA strings. When DNA strings include an option, it
 * is added to the filename with a ?setting=value query string. It needs to be
 * removed to properly access the file name before Drawing.
 *
 * @param {String} _dna The entire newDNA string
 * @returns Cleaned DNA string without querystring parameters.
 */
const removeQueryStrings = (_dna) => {
  const query = /(\?.*$)/;
  return _dna.replace(query, "");
};

const isDnaUnique = (_DnaList = new Set(), _dna = "") => {
  const _filteredDNA = filterDNAOptions(_dna);
  return !_DnaList.has(_filteredDNA);
};

const createDna = (_layers) => {
  let randNum = [];
  _layers.forEach((layer) => {
    var totalWeight = 0;
    layer.elements.forEach((element) => {
      totalWeight += element.weight;
    });
    // number between 0 - totalWeight
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalWeight);
    for (var i = 0; i < layer.elements.length; i++) {
      // subtract the current weight from the random weight until we reach a sub zero value.
      random -= layer.elements[i].weight;
      if (random < 0) {
        return randNum.push(
          `${layer.elements[i].id}:${layer.elements[i].filename}${
            layer.bypassDNA ? "?bypassDNA=true" : ""
          }`
        );
      }
    }
  });
  return randNum.join(DNA_DELIMITER);
};

const writeMetaData = (_data) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${buildDir}/json/_metadata.json`, _data);
};

const saveMetaDataSingleFile = (_editionCount) => {
  let metadata = metadataList.find((meta) => meta.edition == _editionCount);
  debugLogs
    ? console.log(
        `Writing metadata for ${_editionCount}: ${JSON.stringify(metadata)}`
      )
    : null;
  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${buildDir}/json/${_editionCount}.json`,
    JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2)
  );
};

function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex],
    ];
  }
  return array;
}

const startCreating = async () => {
  let layerConfigIndex = 0;
  let editionCount = 1;
  let failedCount = 0;
  let abstractedIndexes = [];
  for (
    let i = network == NETWORK.sol ? 0 : 1;
    i <= layerConfigurations[layerConfigurations.length - 1].growEditionSizeTo;
    i++
  ) {
    abstractedIndexes.push(i);
  }
  if (shuffleLayerConfigurations) {
    abstractedIndexes = shuffle(abstractedIndexes);
  }
  debugLogs
    ? console.log("Editions left to create: ", abstractedIndexes)
    : null;
  while (layerConfigIndex < layerConfigurations.length) {
    const layers = layersSetup(
      layerConfigurations[layerConfigIndex].layersOrder
    );
    while (
      editionCount <= layerConfigurations[layerConfigIndex].growEditionSizeTo
    ) {
      let newDna = createDna(layers);
      if (isDnaUnique(dnaList, newDna)) {
        let results = constructLayerToDna(newDna, layers);
        let loadedElements = [];

        results.forEach((layer) => {
          loadedElements.push(loadLayerImg(layer));
        });

        await Promise.all(loadedElements).then((renderObjectArray) => {
          debugLogs ? console.log("Clearing canvas") : null;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, format.width, format.height);
          if (gif.export) {
            hashlipsGiffer = new HashlipsGiffer(
              canvas,
              ctx,
              `${buildDir}/gifs/${abstractedIndexes[0]}.gif`,
              gif.repeat,
              gif.quality,
              gif.delay
            );
            hashlipsGiffer.start();
          }
          if (background.generate) {
            drawBackground();
          }
          renderObjectArray.forEach((renderObject, index) => {
            drawElement(
              renderObject,
              index,
              layerConfigurations[layerConfigIndex].layersOrder.length
            );
            if (gif.export) {
              hashlipsGiffer.add();
            }
          });
          if (gif.export) {
            hashlipsGiffer.stop();
          }
          debugLogs
            ? console.log("Editions left to create: ", abstractedIndexes)
            : null;
          saveImage(abstractedIndexes[0]);
          addMetadata(newDna, abstractedIndexes[0]);
          saveMetaDataSingleFile(abstractedIndexes[0]);
          console.log(
            `Created edition: ${abstractedIndexes[0]}, with DNA: ${sha1(
              newDna
            )}`
          );
        });
        dnaList.add(filterDNAOptions(newDna));
        editionCount++;
        abstractedIndexes.shift();
      } else {
        console.log("DNA exists!");
        failedCount++;
        if (failedCount >= uniqueDnaTorrance) {
          console.log(
            `You need more layers or elements to grow your edition to ${layerConfigurations[layerConfigIndex].growEditionSizeTo} artworks!`
          );
          process.exit();
        }
      }
    }
    layerConfigIndex++;
  }
  writeMetaData(JSON.stringify(metadataList, null, 2));
};

module.exports = { startCreating, buildSetup, getElements };
```

I tried to use this code by inserting it inside the main document, but it doesn't work.

```
try {
  fs.unlinkSync(path)
  //file removed
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve?